# Inset tool always insets individually

Tags: mesh

I have the following mesh:

[image]

When I try to inset the selected faces, regardless of whether I have Individual ticked or not, Blender will always inset the faces individually like so:

[image]

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried both Local and Global, I've changed the Pivot Point to Bounding Box Center, I've even applied the scale on the object since I heard that could cause issues.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I'm expecting them to inset in the median center of the faces, something like this:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I would imagine this is because of duplicate vertices. Try selecting everything then pressing **M** to merge followed by the "By Distance" option.

Comment: I stand corrected, the merge did find duplicate vertices. That did it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @HISEROD please write up your answer as a separate answer from mine, as I didn't really answer the question and you deserve the reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the inset tool, text will appear in the upper left corner of the screen telling you what the tool options are:

[image: Almost readable tool options]

The last option *Individual* is a toggle.  If it says `ON` rather than `OFF` you get individual faces.  To toggle the tool, simply type <kbd>I</kbd>.

The option setting will be remembered the next time you use the tool.

By the way, this is true for most tools you use in the 3D viewport.  They will display their options in the upper part of the viewport, and the options are usually toggled by typing the key in parenthesis, if they're a toggle.  So, for instance, if you want to toggle *Outset*, you would type <kbd>O</kbd>

---

Possible causes of unexpected behavior could include interior faces or duplicate vertices as shown below.

Interior face:
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Duplicate vertices:
[image: 4]

Comment: I mentioned in the bug description that I've already made sure that the Individual toggle is off and I've made sure the Transform Pivot Point is not the Individual Origins. I wouldn't be asking if I hadn't spent 20 minutes on this one thing already

Comment: thanks both, that's me sorted

Comment: I think that @HISEROD should write up the answer that they added as an edit to this answer and should get the upvoted and accept; as I didn't really answer the question.